# is there a way to get a pcl pointcloud from std::istream instead of a filename

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I want to output a pcl point cloud from an istream (ply file read directly from server and can't be saved locally). Can anyone help if there is a way to achieve this?

I am familiar with `pcl::io::loadPLYFile<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>(std::string fname, *cloud);` but the function I am looking for is of the form `xxxx(std::istream, *cloud);` I tried looking at pcl's codebase in the github but couldn't get anywhere! :(

Comment: After having looked at the the pcl source code for a while, I'm inclined to say _no_, but not confident enough to write that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think PCL has one function to do what you're asking. But looking at the [.ply file format](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/), I'd suggest you do something like following

1. Go through the file line by line
2. Once you find `element vertex X`, keep the number X
3. Once you find `end_header`, start reading vertex values (I'm guessing in the order of x y z r g b a) from the next line to the next `X`th line
4. Assign the read values to a pointcloud you created

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. :)
I ended up converting the file stream into a 2d vector and then constructing point cloud from reading this vector, using it's "at" function.